# use filter only if an attribute exists with map function

Tags: reactjs, filter

Hello I am using filter with map in react.

```
props.types.filter(data => (data.is_active === 1)).map((data, index) => {
// some code.

});
```

I am getting `props.types` in this component. But sometimes props.types does not contain `is_active` property. So in that case, map function doesn't return anything. I want to run `filter` only when `data.is_active` property exists.
How do I do this ?

**UPDATE 1:**
As I said above I want to run filter only if `is_active` is exists but **I will always run map.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to your filter that checks if `is_active` is not set.
This way your `map` will always be executed, except when `is_active` is not 1.

```
props.types
  .filter((data) => data.is_active === undefined || data.is_active === 1)
  .map((data, index) => {
    // some code.
  });
```

Comment: Thats but I tried `(data) => data.is_active && data.is_active === 1)`. But not working.

Comment: Thanks*********but...

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional operator "?" after your filter method.

```
props.types.filter(data => (data.is_active === 1))?.map((data, index) => {
     // some code.
});
```

Comment: You got me wrong. Your solution blocks the map function if `is_active` is not exists ?

Comment: As I said, I want to run filter only if `is_active` is exists, but I will always run map.